# How do i find the mean and median through a csv using an array on a Jframe?

Tags: java, csv, jframe, mean, median

I'm just a tad bit confused, I need to find  the median and mode through this code through an array and I want to input it into a textfield since i'm using Jframes.

This is the code i'm using for the actual CSV document, it already reads the files from the CSV, but the mean and median bit is a bit confusing...

```
public void theSearch() {
try {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Desktop\\Data Set.csv")));
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("H:\\2nd Year\\Programming Group Project\\Data Set.csv")));
        List<String[]> elements = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String line = null;

        while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            elements.add(splitted);               
        }
        br.close();
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));


        String[] columnNames = new String[] {
                "Reporting period", "Period of coverage", "Breakdown", "ONS code", "Level", "Level description", "Gender", "Indicator value", "CI lower", "CI upper", "Denominator", "Numerator" 
            };

        Object[][] content = new Object[elements.size()][13];{
        for(int i=1; i<elements.size(); i++) {
            content[i][0] = elements.get(i)[0];
            content[i][1] = elements.get(i)[1];
            content[i][2] = elements.get(i)[2];
            content[i][3] = elements.get(i)[3];
            content[i][4] = elements.get(i)[4];
            content[i][5] = elements.get(i)[5];
            content[i][6] = elements.get(i)[6];
            content[i][7] = elements.get(i)[7];
            content[i][8] = elements.get(i)[8];
            content[i][9] = elements.get(i)[9];
            content[i][10] = elements.get(i)[10];
            content[i][11] = elements.get(i)[11];
            content[i][12] = elements.get(i)[12];

        }
        };

         jTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(content,columnNames));
         jScrollPane2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 23));
         jTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
         add(jScrollPane2);

        //TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (content, columnNames);
        //JTable jTable = new JTable(model);
        //jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1200, 400));
       // TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorted = new TableRowSorter <TableModel>(model);
       // jTable.setRowSorter(sorted);
       // jTable.setEnabled(false);
       // JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(jTable);

        System.out.println(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your title references CSV, mean, median, arrays and JFrame. But reading the question it seems you are really just asking how to get the mean and median values. Is that correct? If so in future you should simplify the question to focus on the specific piece of information you need.

Comment: Yeah i wan't to implement the mean and median values to an array

Answer (score 0):

To calculate statistics such as mean and median you need to have numbers rather than strings. So the first thing you need to do is to convert the strings you are reading from the file into the appropriate data type. By far the best way to do this in Java is to create a class to represent objects in each row and then turn your rows into a collection of those objects.

I'm not sure what your rows represent so I'll just call the class `Row` here:

```
class Row {
    private final int reportingPeriod;
    private final int level;
    ...

    public Row(String[] values) {
        this.reportingPeriod = Integer.valueOf(values[0]);
        this.level = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
        ...
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}

List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
    rows.add(new Row(line.split(","));
}
```

Or in Java 8:

```
List<Row> rows = br.lines().map(l -> new Row(l.split(","))).collect(toList());
```

To find the median and mean:

```
int[] levels = new int[rows.size()];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    levels[i] = rows.get(i).getLevel();
    sum += levels[i];
}
Arrays.sort(levels);
int median = levels[rows.size() / 2];
double mean = (double)sum / rows.size();
```

In Java 8 this would be:

```
int median = rows.stream().mapToInt(Row::getLevel).sorted().skip(rows.size() / 2).findFirst().get();
double mean = rows.stream().mapToInt(Row::getLevel).average().getAsDouble();
```